# Multi-label Prediction with scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline, multilabel-classification

I have a multilabel prediction with a scikit-learn pipeline. It is working properly in terms of internal testing and getting metrics for each of the label predictions. However, I'm having trouble getting the right structure for data output. When I run code on unseen/external data, it apparently runs through predictions for each of the labels but replaces the values in the same column. So I only get one column of predictions.

This data set involves more than 20 labels (categories), and it's part of an NLP model. Each of the labels is binarized (0 or 1). I am new and really appreciate the help. Thank you!

Here are three parts to the code: (1) pipeline, (2) for loop for test/validation data with fit/predict, and (3) attempts at coding the predict function for external data.

1) Pipeline:

```
SVC_pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', 
TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=LemmaTokenizer(), min_df=8)),
                ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=6)),
            ])
```

2) For loop:

```
for category in categories:
    print('processing {}'.format(category))
    # train
    SVC_pipeline.fit(X_train, train[category])
    # test
    prediction = SVC_pipeline.predict(X_test)
    print('Test accuracy is               
{}'.format(accuracy_score(test[category], prediction)))
```

3) Predict external data:

```
doctext = sampdf['doc_text']
pred = SVC_pipeline.predict(doctext)
```

Also tried this:

```
for category in categories:
    print('... Processing {}'.format(category))
    svcpredict = SVC_pipeline.predict(testthis)
    np.savetxt("/Users/.../Dropbox/.../svcpredicts.csv", svcpredict)
```

I also tried other a few other variations, but they all had the same result. The metrics ran through all labels and gave me varying metrics for each category. But the output only gave me one column of predictions.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_multilabel.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-multilabel-py

Comment: Thank you. In my case, I have labeled categories. I’m training on about 20 known labels and want the predictions to fit these same labels. Most observations have multiple labels.